# Android Activity has destroy after few minutes when app is pause

Tags: android, service, location, background-service

I create an application which get location and send data to server in 5 min intervals. But when my app is paused after 2/3 min app is destroyed. I want to running service till I destroy activity. Please give some suggestion.

Comment: To get some suggestion, give some code.

Comment: Android can kill your app at any time, and the more resources your app is using, the more likely it is to be killed

Comment: Cagri Yalcin, I add some code.

Comment: if you want a *Service*, the why you use the *Activity*?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many reasons lets your app crashes when going background. You should give some code.

Your problem, I think your device is Android O or later. In Android O, if you create a BACKGROUND service, the app will be destroyed in the background, you should use FOREGROUND service instead.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 1):

If you intend your application to work even when the app is not visible to the user, use a Service, which runs in the background. 
Using a basic Service is just as easy as creating an activity, give it a try.

Also, posting relevant code that shows what you've tried could also help. 
Since this app runs in the background, be sure to [optimize usage of location services](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery) so as to save the phone's battery.